# MATLAB - Sampling Random values

Tags: matlab

I want to use randsample to sample values from a matrix, but I want the values sampled to be replaced by zero in the matrix. What do I do/Is there a fuction for this?

Comment: After you replace a number with `0`, do you want to allow the sampler to choose that `0` again? Please rather give some sample input and output data

Comment: I've got it, Matt's answer works, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you don't want to use `randsample` because you have a given matrix (here `M`). You can use `datasample` instead to randomly sample existing data. Then you can use the second output of `datasample` (here `ind`) to address the entries in the original matrix `M` and overwrite them easily.

In the following example operates over the second dimension and takes a selection of columns. If you want a selection of rows, change the third argument of `datasample` to 1 (this is Matlab's default behaviour when no third argument is given).

```
% create random data
M = randi(20,4,10)

% randomly sample data
[Y,ind] = datasample(M,4,2)

% write 0 for the sampled data in original matrix
M(:,ind) = 0
```

*This is the result:*

```
M =
    20    14     6    18     1     9     4    15    11    11
    11     5     9    20     8    19     2     9     3    13
    20    20    16     4     1    16    13    11     4     9
    15     1     4    12    20    18     4    19    11    13
Y =
    18     4    15    14
    20     2     9     5
     4    13    11    20
    12     4    19     1
ind =
     4     7     8     2
M =
    20     0     6     0     1     9     0     0    11    11
    11     0     9     0     8    19     0     0     3    13
    20     0    16     0     1    16     0     0     4     9
    15     0     4     0    20    18     0     0    11    13
```

<sup>Initialized with `rng(4)`.</sup>